# EE2 removal of index.php put my site down.

Tags: mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I followed the user guide (http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html) to remove index.php from the url and now my site is completely down. I can't even access the the system directory. I'm not sure what went wrong. I've tried different .htaccess version and removing the htaccess file, but nothing works. EE requires you in the admin panel to change the name of your site’s index page to be blank, which it seems has completely messed up everything now. Since I can't access the CMS to change the field for the sites index page, is there a way to access file and hard code it manually or somewhere in the database I can fix the problem.

My site is running on a MediaTemple GS if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Have you renamed your system directory? Can we see what your htaccess file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is in your config.php file (system/expressionengine/config) look for this line:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Change to:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

Once you're up and working again, paste your current htaccess file.  Here's the essential bit from my usual build:

```
# ExpressionEngine rewrite to remove index.php from the URL (but allow EE to access EE     folders/files)
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(css=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/%1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|images|themes|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php|admin\.php) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```